# Probability of picking exactly half of the elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, limits

I'm looking for a bijective proof that the probability of picking half the elements in a set (when the probability for any subset of that specific set is the same), goes to 0 as the number of elements in the set goes to infinity.

I.e. prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\!\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}=0$ bijectively.

Edit:
It can be proven that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\!\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Any answer that will prove this fact in a more intuitive way will be accepted, although I'm really hoping to find a nice bijective explanation for why this is true.

Comment: I don't see how you could bijectively calculate a limit...

Comment: @PierreAlvarez You could calculate the magnitude, and provave that the magnitude goes to 0. I don't mean to calculate the limit directly using bijections.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 The probability space defined for each size is different. You can look at them as increasing $\sigma$-algebras if you want, but as you said, the limit won't be a probability space.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Not sure I get your point: infinite families of independent binary random variables can very well be (and are routinely) defined on some unique probability space.

Comment: Maybe I can explain myself better using @Jorge answer bellow.
The entire expression is $o(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$. Can we prove this fact bijectively?

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 I editted the brackets in the question, is that clearer now?

Comment: @S.B. thanks, that's clearer..so you are assuming a uniform distribution over the power set and then an RV that returns the cardinality of each set.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 .Exactly. You can also think ablut it as the probability that assigns to each independent event "i is in the subset" a measure of 0.5

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}=\frac{2n!}{n!^2 2^{2n}}$

we now re-write the numerator as $(2n(2n-2)(2n-4)\dots2)^2\frac{(2n-1)(2n-3)\dots 1}{(2n)(2n-2)\dots2}$.

we call the last fraction $f(n)$ and rewrite again extracting the factors of two from the first part to get:

$(2n)!=2^{2n}n!^2f(n)$. Now to see $f(n)$ goes to zero see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1002803/33907).

So we can now see
$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\!\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}=$ $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\!\frac{2n!}{n!^2 2^{2n}}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{2n}n!^2f(n)}{2^{2n}n!^2}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n)=0$

Comment: "Bijective" proof?

Comment: I don't really know how a bijective proof would look like, no harm was intended

Comment: No harm done. I think that having the algebric proof in hand is sometimes helpfull when trying to find the bijective one.